# Tikz, rotate, how to specify a point as rotating center?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

When I use `rotate` on a node, it seems to be rotated against its `west`(As in figure (up) and (middle)), however, what I meant is to rotate it against its `center`, like (bottom) of figure shows. I didn't find such a parameter in manual....

[image]

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[sampleA/.style={text width=1cm, text height=2cm},
sampleB/.style={text width=1.5cm, text height=.5cm},
every node/.style={draw, rectangle, align=center}]
%% up 
\node (A) at (0,0) [sampleA] {A};
\node[sampleB] (B)  [right=.1cm of A] {B};
%% middle
\node (A) at (0,-3) [sampleA] {A};
\node (B) [sampleB, right=.1cm of A, rotate=-90] {B};
%% bottom
\node (A) at (0,-7) [sampleA] {A};
\node (B) [sampleB, right=.1cm of A, rotate=-90, xshift=-.8cm, yshift=.5cm] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to use `round around`, but it fails:

```
\node (A) at (0,-7) [sampleA] {A};
\node (B3) [sampleB, right=.1cm of A, rotate around={-90:(B3.center)}, xshift=-.8cm, yshift=.5cm] {B};
```

Error says:

> Package pgf Error No shape named B3 is known.

Comment: A node rotate around its anchor. In your code, the `right` option of node `B3` implies the `west` anchor. Add the `anchor=south` option...